# Uri ignore special characters

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I got a string that represent a url and i want to download the content via c#

my url contains [right to left mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) and [left to right mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) %E2%80%8F & %E2%80%8E.

when i paste the url in the browser i can show the file.
when i use the code in .net i get an error ( because .net ignore those marks and doesnt send them in the request.

this is the query string i got

> /MBA%20%281%29/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA%20%28%E2%80%8F%EF%BB%BF13015%E2%80%8E%29%E2%80%8F/%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%99%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%97%D7%9F/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%93%D7%A3%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-2%20%D7%A2%D7%9E-%203%20%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%D7%91.pdf

using fiddle i can that .net send

> /MBA%20(1)/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA%20(%EF%BB%BF13015)/%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%99%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%97%D7%9F/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%93%D7%A3%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-2%20%D7%A2%D7%9E-%203%20%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%D7%91.pdf

youll notice that marks are gone.

any idea how to solve it?

here some code: 
     var s = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/4fsaouo0ob52xkz/MBA%20%281%29/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA%20%28%E2%80%8F%EF%BB%BF13015%E2%80%8E%29%E2%80%8F/%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%99%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%97%D7%9F/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%93%D7%A3%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-2%20%D7%A2%D7%9E-%203%20%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%D7%91.pdf";

```
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {

            using (var sr = client.GetAsync(s).Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr.Headers);
            }

        }
```

I tried to create the uri manually and pass it to the httpClient - save result.
The sr - got 403 error code instead of 200( the link i provided in invalid but the end result is the same).

Comment: OK this issue only happen on .net 4.5 and .net 4.5.1. on .net 4 and 3.5 this issue does not occur

Comment: System.Uri was changed in .net 4.5. Unfortunately, it is used in HttpClient, WebClient and HttpWebrequest.

Comment: @LostInComputer - I read .net 4.5 changed Uri. Is there any way to get pass that? Do an http call without using Uri?

Comment: @Ram Not aware of any built-in .net class that doesn't use Uri internally

Comment: I am receving back Unauthorized Status code

Comment: Have you tried using HttpUtility.UrlDecode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: After the object is Uri it does not matter - But I try to use that as well

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: I created a separate process that runs under .net 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var uri = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/4fsaouo0ob52xkz/MBA%20%281%29/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA%20%28%E2%80%8F%EF%BB%BF13015%E2%80%8E%29%E2%80%8F/%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%99%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%97%D7%9F/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%93%D7%A3%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-2%20%D7%A2%D7%9E-%203%20%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%D7%91.pdf";


       string Url= System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri);
        //objDataToXml.GenerateXml();
       using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
       {

           using (var sr = client.GetAsync(Url).Result)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(sr.Headers);
           }

       }
```